# post request (with body) in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, request

I want to do a POST request which contains a body, I did that with postman but I failed to write that in node.js after many attempts.
Here is a screen in postman which shows the request :

(fixed)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to send the data doing:

```
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

You also need to declare the Content-Length value

```
'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
```

I haven't actually tried it, but usually I send post data this way. Hope this could help.